# Download Image From Site

Tags: css, image, graphics

This site is claiming to prevent the download of images and preventing screenshots. Is this truly possible to stop and can anyone crack it in their demos? What tools can be used to download an image set as a background?

http://www.iptlock.com/how.php

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible, no.

If the client can see it on their screen, then it exists on their computer.  Even if that weren't the case, there is always the whole analog thing (people can literally take a picture of their screen).

Answer (score 1):

If you have chrome: Just go to one of their demos, press ctrl+shift+c, and an inspector will show up, showing you all individual parts of the page. Then select the image from the list (servedemoimg) , right mouse click on it, and you can save the jpg. It is not possible to prevent people from downloading those files. And this company doesn't even make it particularly difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Their scheme "works" by hiding the content whenever a key is pressed or the main window loses focus. They also attempt to detect that something has been copied to the clipboard and they replace it with some text ("It is prohibited to copy distribute or in any way alter these copyrighted images").

That means that if you press any key to copy the content, you'll just get the "locked" graphic. The same goes for switching to another app (like a screen capture app) because the screen capture app will have focus instead of the browser, causing the lock graphic to show. If you do manage to copy something to the clipboard, it immediately replaces the content with the text I mentined above.

Furthermore, their content is a background image so you can't easily print or right-click to copy the image by disabling JS.

However, it's pretty trivial to defeat. My first attempt using IE8 was trivial. When I went to the "protected" page, IE asked me if I wanted to allow the page to access the clipboard, and I clicked "Don't Allow". Then I pressed <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> and was able to paste the content into another program. This worked because that particular key isn't captured by the browser and I didn't allow the page to see my clipboard.

Then I tried again, this time allowing clipboard access. This time I used a screen capture program that automatically captures the foreground window after a set time delay. This worked because I was able to give the browser window focus, and the screen capture utility just saved the image as a file instead of putting it on the clipboard.

Lastly, I just saved the source as a file and saw `background:url(servedemoimg.php?filename=IPTbusiness_graphicdesign_ITB)`. Just putting http://www.iptlock.com/servedemoimg.php?filename=IPTbusiness_lawyer_ITB into my browser's address bar made the complete "protected" content show up for me to download, print, email, etc.